# Scrollbar not working with TLF text with dynamic content in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, tlf

I'm creating a simple Flash project with Flash CS5 and ActionScript 3.

What I want to do is that I want to dynamically update a TLF text container with given source and destination, something like `loadData(text_placeX, "markup.xml");` anywhere that I want.

It's working like a charm, but the problem is I can't use any scroll-bar for my text. I have added a `UIScrollBar` to text container and it's working with the default text that I've putted into text container, but when I update container with my data it's not working. What am I missing?

Another question is that how I can empty my text container before loading new data in it?

My code is:

```
import fl.text.TLFTextField;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
import flashx.textLayout.container.ContainerController;
import flashx.textLayout.elements.TextFlow;
import flashx.textLayout.conversion.TextConverter;
import fl.controls.ScrollBar;

var ldr:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var flow:TextFlow = new TextFlow();

function loadData(text_place, fileURL:String):void {
    text_place.border = true;
    ldr.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
    ldr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(evt:Event){ ldr_complete(text_place) }, false, 0, true);
    ldr.load(new URLRequest(fileURL));
    ldr.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loadError);
}

function ldr_complete(text_place:TLFTextField):void {
    ldr.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, ldr_complete);
    ldr.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loadError);
    initText(text_place, ldr.data);
}

function loadError(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
    trace("Error loading an external file. The server may be busy. Try refreshing the page.");
}

function initText(text_place:TLFTextField, fileContent):void {
    flow = TextConverter.importToFlow(fileContent, TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT);
    flow.flowComposer.addController(new ContainerController(text_place, text_place.width, text_place.height));
    flow.flowComposer.updateAllControllers();
}
```

**UPDATE:** When I skip using of `initText` function contents and instead I use `text_place.tlfMarkup = fileContent;` it works; but my option on `TextFlow` is missing. And also I was missing "update scrollbar" after putting content in text-field.

Comment: I was going to take a look at this, but I have no idea how your stage elements are laidd out. Any chance you can put your fla up to an FTP so I can download it and take a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this line may be the problem:

```
ldr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(evt:Event){ ldr_complete(text_place) }, false, 0, true);
```

You have an anonymous function here (`function(evt:Event){...`) which passes the object `text_place` to the function `ldr_complete()`.  However, you do not have access to `text_place`, since it is a variable declared within a different scope.  If you make the function into a named one, you will not assume that you have that access.  E.g.,

```
function loadCompleteHnd(evt:Event):void{
[...]
}
```

However, you still have to gain access to the object in `text_place`.  So, you can make `text_place` a class-level (global) variable, and set that variable whenever.  But that may run the risk of creating a race condition -- if you have a slow load, you might be trying change that object from two places at once.

Another option is to create an entirely new `Event` which extends the `Event.COMPLETE` setup.  At that point, you can create another parameter for the `Event.COMPLETE` listener to use.  This is complicated, and a bit of a learning curve, but it makes events more versatile.

In either case, you may want to set up a flag that tells you whether something else is editing the same object.  It's not foolproof, but it can save some headaches.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but I needed to send two parameters to a function that only captures an event; so I made it this way. I checked my code line by line, and it turned out that problem is in textflow, without using it, my code works like a charm but I'm missing too many option without textflow.